# Com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Certificate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) ‘/root/.docker/certs’ doesn’t exist General Discussions

Tags: docker, docker-api

I try to make simple Docker-Java application on Centos 7. Building image and container invocation are successful. This is my code:

```
    public class JavaClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DockerClientConfig config = DockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                    .withRegistryUrl("unix:///var/run/docker.sock")
                    .withDockerCertPath("/root/.docker/certs")
                    .withRegistryUsername("user01")
                    .withRegistryPassword("111111")
                    .withRegistryEmail("user01@naver.com")
                    .build();

        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

        System.out.println(dockerClient.versionCmd());

    }

 }
```

However I can't find the Docker security files at all. Docker installation, building images and container invocation have no problem. But I don't know where SSL files in Centos 7 are. This is the exception message

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Certificate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) '/root/.docker/certs' doesn't exist.
at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig.checkDockerCertPath(DockerClientConfig.java:112)
at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig.(DockerClientConfig.java:85)
at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig$DockerClientConfigBuilder.build(DockerClientConfig.java:432)
at com.aaa.docker.JavaClient.main(JavaClient.java:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create empty directory '/root/.docker/certs'.

I found another solution which not requires to create directories.
You can just create properties, like environment variables and set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY to "0". In this case, docker won't look for any certificates.

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY", "0");
    properties.setProperty("DOCKER_HOST", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock");
    final DockerClientConfig.DockerClientConfigBuilder configBuilder = new DockerClientConfig.DockerClientConfigBuilder().withProperties(properties);
    return DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(configBuilder).build();
```